# three.js files are not loading for me but only html

Tags: amazon-web-services, three.js

when i amplify it in only shows the html code (text) when i go to the terminal it shows this
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I tried to install three.js again and import it i also tried taking the build file out from the node modules files

i have triedto install three.js again and import it i also tried taking the build file out from the node modules files